# Display full image in a box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input that when selecting an image it fills all this box ...
In order to completely fill this box I used 100% height and width ... in fact the image occupies the entire box, but not all of its details are visible.

Is there any way to get the image to occupy 100% but in which all your content is visible?

My problem:

**Original Image**

[image: Image 1]

**Picture inside the box (What I have)**

[image: Image2]

As you can see, the image occupies the whole box (it's correct) but the problem is that the full image doesn't appear :(

Any solution?

Thanks!

[My code and test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmdm5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<div class="drop">
  <div class="cont" *ngIf="urls.length === 0">
    <div class="browse" >
        Upload files
      </div>     
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="urls.length > 0">
      <img [src]="urls[0]">
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

**css**

```
.drop {
  margin-left: 32px;
    width: 928px;
  height: 696px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    /* margin: auto; */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  /*&:hover
    cursor: pointer
    background: #f5f5f5*/;
}

.drop .cont {
    width: 500px;
    height: 170px;
    color: #8E99A5;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.drop .cont i {
    font-size: 400%;
    color: #8E99A5;
    position: relative;
}


.drop .cont .browse {
margin: 10px 25%;
padding: 8px 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
background: #ECF2F9;
text-align: center;
font: Bold 13px/20px Noto Sans;
letter-spacing: 0;
color: #4D4F5C;
}

.drop input {
  width: 928px;
  height: 650px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#list {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}


#list .thumb {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}

img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated. Try this.

```
 img {
    height: 100% !important;
}

   .abc {
   width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

<div class="abc" *ngIf="urls.length > 0">
      <img [src]="urls[0]">
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the width is not 100% due to the height of the image, I tested it as another image and it was perfect! If you can improve, perfect, otherwise it can look like this is already quite well

Comment: when you give to parent fixed width and height so img also need to have  width and height  that fill his aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line:

```
.drop {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you change it to `overflow: visible/scroll` it will work.
If you don't want the image to scroll you could edit the css like this:

```
img {
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but is there any way to display the entire image without scrolling, also increasing the size of the box, I don't want that :(

Comment: I've updated my answer so you don't have to scroll, it should work like that

Comment: It shows the image with the box dimensions (right) but does not show the entire contents of the image :(

Comment: Could it be that you forgot overflow: visible?

Comment: Sorry I had not changed that. Now the image is complete, but higher than the box.

Comment: In the latter case I can use overflow: scroll; so it shows the whole image inside the box but with the scroll ... but if there was a better solution, that was ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your giving a fixed height to the parent container, what you have to add is this:

```
.drop{ 
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.drop>img{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It shows the image with the box dimensions (right) but does not show the entire contents of the image :(

Comment: You have to apply the image css to the div which is wrapping it, but instead witdh: 100%, use this: width: auto; height: 100%;